# How can I see the other users information when I click the button?

Tags: reactjs

In the below function, there is information of a user which is "temp_id". When the button is clicked, I want to pass this "temp_id" to below file.

```
 const temp_id = {
        description: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printin...',
        email: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        name: 'john',
        private: false,
        rating: 0,
        role: 'PATIENT',
        status: 'Face with Tears of Joy',
        surname: 'cash',
        username: 'kibitzer',
    };
    const TestMeetingCreate = props => {

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={temp_id}>
                    {' '}
                    <Link to={ROUTES.PROFILE}>Go to profile</Link>
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

When I click the PersonalInfo page from the navigation, I can see all the information of the "user" that I get from firebase which is ok. But what I want is, if I access this page from the above page, I want to see the temp_id's data. I defined the "temp_id" in a const but I can not access it by this way.
When I click the button, the "temp_id" remains null, so it shows the "user" data. How can I solve this?

```
    const PersonalInfo = props => {
        const { user, openSettings, temp_id } = props;


        return !temp_id ? (
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 pl-5 pr-5 pt-2 pb-4 profile-info">            
                <div className="row mt-2">
                            <span>{`${user.name} ${user.surname}`}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="row mt-2 h-auto">
                    <span>{`${user.description}`}</span>
                </div>
                 <div className="row mt-3">
                    <button
                        className="btn btn-secondary btn-block"
                        type="button"
                        onClick={openSettings}
                    >
                        Profili Düzenle
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="row mt-2">
                    <div className="col-12">
                            <div className="col-12 no-padding">                          
                                <span className="align-middle">{` ${user.email}`}</span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 pl-5 pr-5 pt-2 pb-4 profile-info">
                <div className="row mt-2">
                    <div className="col-lg-9 col-9">
                        <div className="row font-18 font-weight-bold">
                            <span>{`${temp_id.name} ${temp_id.surname}`}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row font-weight-lighter font-italic">
                            <span>{`${temp_id.username}`}</span>
                        </div>
                   </div>  
              </div>
                <div className="row mt-2 h-auto">
                    <span>{`${temp_id.description}`}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="row mt-2">
                                <span className="align-middle">{` ${temp_id.email}`}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `Redirect`  instead of a `Link`.  Since you are using a button click, what i would suggest is to set a state on the click of button with desired value.

Then use the below syntax

```
 <Redirect
  to={{
   pathname: "/login",
   state: { temp_id: [your value or variable] }
 }}
/>
```

You an access this state in your `PersonalInfo` component using the below syntax

```
 this.props.location.state.temp_id
```

Note: you need to wrap your Component in `withRouter` or use the router hook to access the location object.